# Got a job offer but still interviewing other companies. Do's and dont's?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, france

I'm currently employed at A. I want some change and salary increase so I started interviewing other companies and I'm also interviewing for another position in A.

I got a good job offer from B, with a salary above what I asked the other recruiters (5K/10% more) and more so above what I'm paid at A (10k more salary-wise, 5K minus benefits in A ).

B and other recruiters know that I'm interviewing. I haven't yet interviewed for the other position at A but given that I have offers elsewhere I'm planning to be honest on the subject.

I'd like to continue interviewing some positions that could be interesting, I'd like to know what I can do and what I should not do with a job offer in hand?

This is in France

Edit: Not a duplicate of [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa).

Before getting the job offer from B I told them when I would be ready to give an answer and that I would compare them to other offers so there is no stalling involved. My question is more about how to use a job offer as a tool in negotiation or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple offers to negotiate a higher salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9338/how-to-use-multiple-offers-to-negotiate-a-higher-salary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered many times here, you should look other questions like this to get more ideas.

If you have an offer of a company X, you have to agree with them how much time do you have to give a final answer. In the meantime, you can still have interviews with other companies and you can use the offer you already have as a leverage. You can tell company Y that if they are interested they have to make a move before the expiration date of the offer of company X.
You don't have to give every detail, just that you have an offer and if offered less money you can say that you have a better one, but there's no need to say how much.